# mpi4py: python complains MPI has no member named 'COMM_WORLD'

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am new to mpi4py. I followed the User Guide and installed the package. The import of this package doesn't raise an error. However, when I tried to run `mpiexec -n 5 python -m mpi4py helloword`, which is provided by the guide as a quick test of successful installation, I got `/usr/bin/python has no module named mpi4py`. 
And when I tried to run the tutorial script, the editor complained that 

`severity: 'Error'
message: 'E1101:Module 'mpi4py.MPI' has no 'COMM_WORLD' member'
at: '3,8'
source: 'pylint'`

My code is here:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = {'a': 7, 'b': 3.14}
    comm.send(data, dest=1, tag=11)
    print('I am {}. I send {}.'.format(rank, data))
elif rank == 1:
    data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=11)
    print('I am {}. I receive {}'.format(rank, data))
```

Some information may help: 
python version 3.5.2,
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS,
mpi4py version 2.0.0

`ompi_info` gives:

```
                 Package: Open MPI buildd@lgw01-57 Distribution
                Open MPI: 1.10.2
  Open MPI repo revision: v1.10.1-145-g799148f
   Open MPI release date: Jan 21, 2016
                Open RTE: 1.10.2
  Open RTE repo revision: v1.10.1-145-g799148f
   Open RTE release date: Jan 21, 2016
                    OPAL: 1.10.2
      OPAL repo revision: v1.10.1-145-g799148f
       OPAL release date: Jan 21, 2016
                 MPI API: 3.0.0
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can't you simply do `mpirun -np 5 python helloworld` instead ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks for your reply. I tried your advice and got `python: can't open file 'helloworld': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
`. Am I supposed to run this command under a specific directory?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Sorry, I found the directory to run the helloworld script. However, the `ImportError: no module named mpi4py` still exists. But when I run `import mpi4py` in the python console, there is no problem.

Comment: did you set some environment variables before running `import mpi4py` in the console ? if yes, you might have to manually export them (e.g. `mpirun -x ENV_VARIABLE ...`). does the MPI task run on the same hosts than mpirun ? if not, then check mpi4py is installed on all your nodes